# Express.JS not recognizing required js file's functions

Tags: javascript, express

Even though, I've imported the JS file that includes the function that I will use, Node.JS says that it is undefined.

```
require('./game_core.js');

Users/dasdasd/Developer/optionalassignment/games.js:28
    thegame.gamecore = new game_core( thegame );
                       ^
ReferenceError: game_core is not defined
```

Do you have any idea what's wrong? Game_core includes the function:

```
var game_core = function(game_instance){....};
```

Answer (score 4):

Add to the end of game_core.js:

```
module.exports = {  
    game_core : game_core  
}
```

to games.js:

```
var game_core = require('./game_core').game_core(game_istance);
```

Answer (score 2):

Requiring a module in Node doesn't add its contents to the global scope. Every module is wrapped in its own scope, so you have to [export public names](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports):

```
// game_core.js
module.exports = function (game_instance){...};
```

Then keep a reference in your main script to the exported object:

```
var game_core = require('./game_core.js');
...
thegame.gamecore = new game_core( thegame );
```

You can read more about it in the docs: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach:

```
if( 'undefined' != typeof global ) {
    module.exports = global.game_core = game_core;
}
```